# What should I do when an answer has been added as comment?

Tags: support, faq, comments

I have found a question without an answer, but there is a comment that answers it.

What should be done in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to write an exhaustive answer basing on what reported on that comment, you can write an answer. You should first comment suggesting to the user who wrote the comment to write it as answer; If that user doesn't add his own answer, then you can write the answer yourself, but:

- You should give enough time for the user who wrote the comment to write an answer before to write your own answer
- You should give credit to the user who wrote the comment that helped you in understanding what the answer was

Instead of an answer like *it is not possible to achieve what you want*, a more exhaustive answer should be given, for example explaining in detail why what the OP wants to achieve cannot be achieved.